# TQSL to reformat records with duplicate data into one record

Tags: sql, sql-server

we have a table that is being provided to us where there are lots of duplicated data in then rows and the only difference is opening and closing times for a certain day of the week - data is provided in this way and the client will not chnage things from their end.

```
 Col1 Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   Col6    Col7
 1    Shop1  Mon    open   6am    Close   4pm
 2    Shop1  Tue    Open   6am    Close   5pm
 3    shop1  Wed    Open   6am    Close   4pm
 4    Shop2  Mon    open   10am   Close   3pm
 5    Shop2  Tue    open   11am   Close   2pm
```

How could the information be stored/presented in the following way using TSQL so that I can retrieve the data from a table or preferably a view - so I don't have to run the data through e.g. a PHP program to do the formating for me? I deally of the data can be in a format that we can read straight from a table/view that would be ideal/

```
 Col1 Col2  Col3 Col4  Col5  Col6   Col7  col8  col9  col10 Col11 Col12    
 1    Shop1 Mon  open  6am   Close  4pm   Tue   Open  6am   Close 5pm
 2    Shop2 Mon  open  10am  close  4pm   Tue   open  11am  close 2pm
```

I know exactly how many columns I will need fro opening closing time i.e. 5 columns for each day of the week so creating the table to store the information is not an issue and does not change

Kind regards
Taki

Comment: You should keep this normalized and not the format you are trying to do. And there is no need for a column with the values "open" and "Close". This could easily be condensed to Shop, OperationDay, OpenTime, CloseTime. You don't need 12 columns for this.

Comment: would the Col be extended up to the number of days there will be? ex. Shop1 has Wed and should that be from Col13 to Col17?

Comment: Hello, you are correct, I do not require the open and close columns. I deally the new table should just have shop1, day1, opentime, closetime, day2, opentime, closetime,...  Can this be done using TSQL? Please note, the original data is provided by a third party and they will not change the data they are providing. We have to reformat it at our end, hence my question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    Col2 CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Col3 CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Col4 CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    Col5 TIME(0) NOT NULL,
    Col6 CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Col7 TIME(0) NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #TestData (Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7) VALUES 
    ('Shop1', 'Mon', 'open', '6am ', 'Close', '4pm'),
    ('Shop1', 'Tue', 'Open', '6am ', 'Close', '5pm'),
    ('shop1', 'Wed', 'Open', '6am ', 'Close', '4pm'),
    ('Shop2', 'Mon', 'open', '10am', 'Close', '3pm'),
    ('Shop2', 'Tue', 'open', '11am', 'Close', '2pm');


-- SELECT * FROM #TestData td;'
--============================================================

SELECT 
    Col1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY td.Col2),
    td.Col2,
    Col3 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 1 THEN td.Col3 END),
    Col4 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 1 THEN 'open' END),
    Col5 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 1 THEN col5 END),
    Col6 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 1 THEN 'close' END),
    Col7 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 1 THEN col7 END),

    Col8 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 2 THEN td.Col3 END),
    Col9 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 2 THEN 'open' END),
    Col10 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 2 THEN col5 END),
    Col11 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 2 THEN 'close' END),
    Col12 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 2 THEN col7 END),

    Col13 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 3 THEN td.Col3 END),
    Col14 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 3 THEN 'open' END),
    Col15 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 3 THEN col5 END),
    Col16 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 3 THEN 'close' END),
    Col17 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 3 THEN col7 END),

    Col18 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 4 THEN td.Col3 END),
    Col19 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 4 THEN 'open' END),
    Col20 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 4 THEN col5 END),
    Col21 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 4 THEN 'close' END),
    Col22 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 4 THEN col7 END),

    Col23 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 5 THEN td.Col3 END),
    Col24 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 5 THEN 'open' END),
    Col25 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 5 THEN col5 END),
    Col26 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 5 THEN 'close' END),
    Col27 = MAX(CASE WHEN dn.DayNum = 5 THEN col7 END)
FROM 
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CASE td.Col3
                                WHEN 'Mon' THEN 1
                                WHEN 'Tue' THEN 2
                                WHEN 'Wed' THEN 3
                                WHEN 'Thu' THEN 4
                                WHEN 'Fri' THEN 5
                            END) ) dn (DayNum)
GROUP BY
    td.Col2;
```

Results...

```
Col1                 Col2  Col3 Col4 Col5             Col6  Col7             Col8 Col9 Col10            Col11 Col12            Col13 Col14 Col15            Col16 Col17            Col18 Col19 Col20            Col21 Col22            Col23 Col24 Col25            Col26 Col27
-------------------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------- ----- ---------------- ---- ---- ---------------- ----- ---------------- ----- ----- ---------------- ----- ---------------- ----- ----- ---------------- ----- ---------------- ----- ----- ---------------- ----- ----------------
1                    Shop1 Mon  open 06:00:00         close 16:00:00         Tue  open 06:00:00         close 17:00:00         Wed   open  06:00:00         close 16:00:00         NULL  NULL  NULL             NULL  NULL             NULL  NULL  NULL             NULL  NULL
2                    Shop2 Mon  open 10:00:00         close 15:00:00         Tue  open 11:00:00         close 14:00:00         NULL  NULL  NULL             NULL  NULL             NULL  NULL  NULL             NULL  NULL             NULL  NULL  NULL             NULL  NULL
```

Comment: Thanks you Jason. I ahve tried your method and it works well. Thanks heaps. Cheers! Chris

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. And thank you for the good feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

This query will not be very efficient and I would not recommend putting it in this format directly from the SQL query, but it should be possible to do something like the following assuming your data continues to follow the same format you posted above.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Col1,
    Col2,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col3 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Mon'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col4 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Mon'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col5 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Mon'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col6 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Mon'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col7 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Mon'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col3 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Tue'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col4 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Tue'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col5 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Tue'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col6 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Tue'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col7 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Tue'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col3 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Wed'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col4 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Wed'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col5 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Wed'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col6 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Wed'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col7 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Wed'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col3 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Thur'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col4 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Thur'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col5 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Thur'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col6 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Thur'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col7 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Thur'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col3 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Fri'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col4 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Fri'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col5 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Fri'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col6 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Fri'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col7 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Fri'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col3 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Sat'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col4 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Sat'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col5 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Sat'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col6 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Sat'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col7 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Sat'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col3 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Sun'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col4 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Sun'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col5 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Sun'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col6 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Sun'),
    (SELECT TOP 1 Col7 FROM ShopTable st_inner WHERE st_inner.Col1 = st.Col1 AND st_inner.Col3 = 'Sun')
```

Comment: thanks Carl. I wrote the SQL using your example and yes it does work. My SQL is not the best and your example has helped me understand SQL taht little bit more. I will also look at other responses below before deciding on a final solution. Thanks heaps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way to test this query, but basically you need something like this:

```
SELECT mon.col2, MonStart, MonEnd, TueStart, ... 
FROM 
(
    SELECT distinct Col2,
    CASE col3 WHEN 'Mon' THEN Col5 ELSE NULL END as MonStart,
    CASE col3 WHEN 'Mon' THEN Col7 ELSE NULL END as MonEnd,
    FROM table
) mon
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT distinct Col2,
    CASE col3 WHEN 'Tue' THEN Col5 ELSE NULL END as TueStart,
    CASE col3 WHEN 'Tue' THEN Col7 ELSE NULL END as TueEnd,
    FROM table
) tue on mon.col2 = tue.col2
INNR JOIN 
...
```

Like mentioned in the comments, you don't need extra columns for Open/Close status, just give your columns the right names.

Comment: Thank you Lamar. I will also try your method however I have opted to go with Jason's solution. Apprecaite your time and effort